# ALU NOOP case infers a latch: Is this OK?

Tags: verilog, hdl, alu

I'm designing an ALU in Verilog with a combinational `always` block and cases for every `opcode`. In the case of `NOOP`, nothing should happen, so I'm just setting `result = result`.  I understand why this infers a latch.  My question is: is there a better way or is an inferred latch the correct decision in this case?

```
always@(Rdest, Rsrc, opcode, reset) begin
  case(opcode)
    ...
    default:
    NOOP: result = result; //  Infers a latch
  endcase
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it should be simple to avoid the latch.  You can set `result` to a constant value, such as 0.  The logic that uses `result` probably ignores it when the ALU executes a `NOOP` anyway:

```
  case(opcode)
    ...
    ADD     : result = a + b;
    NOOP    : result = 0; // some known value  
    default : result = 0; // some known value 
  endcase
```

It is good to avoid latches in many cases due to their timing issues.  See also: [Why are inferred latches bad?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38645/why-are-inferred-latches-bad)